# __init__ Python Syntax

Tags: python, class

I created a class for Food items. I'm wondering why in `def __init__(self, type)` there are two arguments but when I call `Food('Meat')` I only pass one argument. I assume this is because `__init__` is special somehow?

```
class Food(object):

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def cook_food_item(self):
        if self.type == 'Meat':
            print 'Grill it!'
        elif self.type == 'Vegetable':
            print 'Boil it!'
        elif self.type == 'Dairy':
            print 'Churn it!'

hot_dog = Food('Meat')
hot_dog.cook_food_item()
```

Comment: Have you read the basic class tutorials? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Off topic: Don't use any built-in function as variable name.

Comment: @zoosuck rarely would that matter in a method argument. It's more an issue when you assign something globally to overwrite a built-in like `sum = a + b + c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about `__init__` here.

In Python, you have two kinds of methods: bound and unbound. Methods defined in a class are usually bound, which let you write `myobj.mymethod()` instead of `MyClass.mymethod(myobj)`. Unbound methods have no `self` argument and act just like regular functions.

To illustrate the point, you can create an unbound method like this:

```
def myfunction(x):
    return x

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.unbound = myfunction

    def bound(self, x):
        print('MyClass.bound called with', self)
        return x

myobj = MyClass()
print(myobj.unbound(42))
print(myobj.bound(42))
```

Note that `myfunction` (and therefore `myobj.unbound`) have no access to `self` unless you explicitly pass it in. So in general, bound methods like `MyClass.bound` are the tool of choice when writing classes. `__init__` is no different. It wouldn't be very useful as an unbound method.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is special indeed because it's a [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#construction), although that's not what makes it receive `self` as a first parameter. Being a class method does that. Every method receives `self` as a first argument, which is passed automatically by Python. I strongly recommend you read the Python basics, like [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), in this case.

Answer (score 0):

All methods in a class pass the class instance as their first argument, including `__init__`. This is true for the other method in your class as well: `def cook_food_item(self)`.

If you had another method that took an actual argument, you'd put that argument after `self`, leaving something like:

```
class Food(object):
    ...

    def eat_with(self, drink):
        print("Eating a " + self.type + " while drinking a " + drink)

>>> hot_dog = Food("hot dog")
>>> hot_dog.eat_with("coke")
Eating a hot dog while drinking a coke
```

Behind the scenes this is doing something *kind of like*

```
>>> hot_dog.eat_with("coke")
# becomes something resembling
hot_dog.__class__.eat_with(hot_dog, "coke") # hot_dog.__class__ is Food
```